# Apex Update of Record Type fails

Tags: apex, update, record

I hope you can help me with my problem.
I am trying to update a record with Apex Code using the workbench.
The Code compiles and so I thought it is fine.
The code updares the wrongly set record type to the correct one. But when I look into the record then in Salesforce it is still showing the old one, so no update did happen...
Any ideas?

The code is

```
    List<Quote> cnts = [SELECT Id FROM Quote WHERE Id = '012D00000003EnX'];
for(Quote c : cnts){
c.RecordTypeId = '012D00000003EnX';
}
update cnts;
```

and the result is

```
    Execute Anonymous: List<Quote> cnts = [SELECT Id FROM Quote WHERE Id = '012D00000003EnX'];
Execute Anonymous: for(Quote c : cnts){
Execute Anonymous: c.RecordTypeId = '012D00000003EnX';
Execute Anonymous: }
Execute Anonymous: update cnts;
11:02:34.036 (36889804)|EXECUTION_STARTED
11:02:34.036 (36921042)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
11:02:34.060 (60446480)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
11:02:34.061 (61663989)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

but when I open up the Quote it has still the old record type....

TIA!

Answer (score 2):

Check your code you are updating Quotes to the exact same record type as the one queried. 
**012D00000003EnX**

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you so much! Sitting in fron of APEX Code too long now! Thanks for the hint!